# Newsgroup classification

Tags: classification, text-mining

Currently our company, has a special user forum.
The main forum is about specific topic: SIP protocol.
Im trying to understand what would be a good approach to classify the top 10 issues customers report in the forum, 
Example:

```
Installation, Crash, Media, Database, etc.
```

What would be a good approach to start classifying the threads, currently each thread is in a CSV file.
I though of doing the following:

1. Tokenization
2. Remove stop words
3. Extract top terms per thread
4. Count all Top issues across all threads and display top words.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have pre-defined categories, or are trying to determine them from the data?

Comment: I don't have predefined categories as u said trying to determine them from the data

Comment: Another question: Can a thread be considered to be in more than one category at the same time - e.g. Crash and Database - or are you looking to strictly classify into most-appropriate issue for each thread (I think this will be harder). Note I don't know enough to answer your question, just I believe that this information will be useful to someone who can.

Comment: Yes that's an option too, each thread can contain multiple topics thanks for commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case boils down to categorizing news feed on an online forum and then finding out top-n categories. I would suggest you look at this [Hacker News Categorizer developed by MonekyLearn](https://blog.monkeylearn.com/hacker-news-categorizer-with-monkeylearn/). This way you can understand how to get started with such projects.

PS : I am **not** affiliated with MonkeyLearn.